# How can I group jQuery objects without using selectors?

Tags: jquery, wrapall

The jQuery.wrapAll function takes a dom subtree and wraps it around a jQuery object. I want to  do that but without aquiring the target jQuery object via selector: I have a bunch of references to jQuery wrapped DOM elements and I want to apply wrapAll to all of them. Is it possible to do it without assigning a common class and selecting them through the class?

Comment: What's the problem? If you have the references, can't you just call myJqueryRef.wrapAll(...)?

Comment: i have many references, not one reference. I want to combine them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add elements to a jQuery object using the [`add` function](http://api.jquery.com/add/). `add` accepts a selector (adds matching elements), a raw DOM element (adds it), an HTML fragment (creates the element(s) and adds them), and a jQuery object (adds all of the elements in it). That last probably matches what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, add them all to the same object.

```
obj1.add(obj2).add(obj3).wrapAll('<div class="contentwrapper" />');
```